# iPadでの印刷

Tags: ios

iPadを用いたシステム構築を行なっています。
PWAを用いたサービスで、オフラインで使用することが前提です。
最終的に、「ご来場引換券を出力」をタップすると、引換券がプリンターから出力されるような仕組みを考えています。このような仕組みを構築することは可能でしょうか。
具体的にご教示いただけましたら幸いです。

Comment: オフラインはあくまでグローバルなネットワークがということで、プリンタとはローカルでのオンライン接続可能ということですか？

Comment: iPadでのプリントは、インターネット経由を想定していません。

Comment: プリンタとの接続方法などはこれから考えていく感じです。

Comment: 「iPad 印刷」と検索するだけで"AirPrint"という機能に関する情報が出てきます。AirPrintに関する情報は既に検討済みでしょうか？

Comment: これから検討してみます。

Answer (score 1):

こんな感じでPC内蔵のプリンタがあります。
直接接続もワイヤレス接続もあります。
この中でWebサーバーを立ち上げれば、出来るでしょう。

[レシートプリンター TM-T70II-DT2](https://www.epson.jp/products/receiptprinter/tmt702dt2/)

こうしたSDKもあります。

[レシートプリンター｜開発支援ツールのご紹介](https://partner.epson.jp/support/small_printer/develop/)

上記はEPSONですが、他のメーカーでもこうした機種やサービス/SDKは揃っていますよ。

[小型プリンター|スター精密](https://www.star-m.jp/products/s_print/index.html)
[システムインテグレーター・アプリ開発者様向け mCollection紹介サイト](https://www.star-m.jp/products/s_print/mcollection/lp/)

[業務用プリンター|シチズン・システムズ](http://www.citizen-systems.co.jp/printer/index.html)
[スマート端末から印刷しよう！](http://www.citizen-systems.co.jp/printer/special/smart_print/)